# Cannot return HTML from a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My code fails to return HTML from a Controller. The browser returns HTTP ERROR 500 - "This page does not work".

The Controller is written in .net core 3.1. Here is the code:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ContentResult>> GetInformation()
    {
        string s = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>.....";
        return base.Content(s, "text/html");
    }
}
```

However, returning a plain string works: (using `string` instead of `ContentResult`. However, this string is not interpreted as HTML and is written directly to the browser)

```
[ApiController]
[Route("")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetInformation()
    {
        string s = @"something";
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> public async Task<ActionResult<ContentResult>> GetInformation()
> ```

Because you declare that the action returns an `ActionResult<ContentResult>`, I expect that the ASP.NET Core serialisation process attempts to serialise the `ContentResult` you return as a JSON object. This is neither intended nor something the framework can manage.

[Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types) goes into the details, but a more typical method signature for your scenario would look like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetInformation()
```

You could also specify `ContentResult`, which implements `IActionResult`, if you'd prefer to do that:

```
public async Task<ContentResult> GetInformation()
```

`IActionResult` allows an action to return different responses in different situations, using e.g. `BadRequest`, `Content`, or `Ok`.